# How to get Ubercart to send email with condition "Its been 2 days, order has not been approved"

Tags: drupal, ubercart

Ubercart 2.x on D6:

I have two roles.

- Branch
- Branch Approver.

If Branch makes an order, it does not get get approved instantly, the Branch Approver has to update the order status to approved.

If the Branch Approver does not do this after 2 days of order being submitted, I want them to receive an order-email, or a notice about this.

How can I configure UC to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with Ubercart, so it might have something build it to support this.

But if not, why not use a hook_cron in a custom module, to check all orders that have not been approved. If one or more have not yet been approved for 2 days, send the Branch Approvers a mail.